# Fill up a ContentControl in a single line

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, contentcontrol

I have created a UserControl file, which I'd like to resuse a couple of times in my UWP app. I've already created a `UC_BackToMainMenu` file.

Now I can do this in the xaml part:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="backToMainMenu">   </ContentControl>
```

and this in the code behind:

```
backToMainMenu.Content = new UC_BackToMainMenu();
```

but since I'm going to reuse this a couple of times, I'd ideally want it all to be a single line, in the xaml part. Unfortunatly when I try to do something like `Content="UC_BackToMainMenu"` I get just the plain text, instead of the actual file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would do that, but I'm a but puzzled as to WHY you would want the UserControl inside a content control when you could just use the UserControl directly.

```
<ContentControl><local:UC_BackToMainMenu/></ContentControl>
```

In order for this to work you will have to define the clr namespace that the user control exists in at the top of your XAML file. Usually it looks like something like this:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Example.NameSpace"
```

but you will have to adjust it for you project's namespace.

Comment: Yes, that worked. I did it 'my way' cause that's how I was taught. Anyway, things worked out in the end, though I had some trouble with the namespaces. Thanks again!